# Declaring a method that uses the subtype class in its signature?

Tags: scala, types, subtyping

I have defined a trait `Mergeable` that represents a value that can be merged with another of its kind, but I'm having trouble declaring the types correctly.

```
trait Mergeable[T] {
  def value: Option[T]
  def merge(other: ???): ???
}

trait SummingInt extends Mergeable[Int] {
  def merge(other: SummingInt): SummingInt = {
    val sum = for {
      i1 <- value
      i2 <- other.value
    } yield i1 + i2
    sum orElse this orElse other
  }
}

trait MultiplyingInt extends Mergeable[Int] {
  def merge(other: MultiplyingInt): MultiplyingInt = {
    val product = for {
      i1 <- value
      i2 <- other.value
    } yield i1 * i2
    product orElse this orElse other
  }
}
```

I want to require that all `Mergeable` define a method `merge` that merges it with another *of it's own kind*. So it is illegal to merge a `SummingInt` with a `MultiplyingInt`.

If I choose:

```
def merge(other: Mergeable[T]): Mergeable[T]
```

Then I lose that guarantee of only merging like-with-like. But if I *don't* define `merge` on `Mergeable`, then I cannot write this method *which would make my life a whole lot simpler*:

```
def mergeTwo[T <: Mergeable](first: T, second: T) = first merge second
```

Even though `mergeTwo` can guarantee that `first` and `second` are of the same type and thus are safe to merge!

Does the Scala language make it at all possible for me to define `merge` at the level of `Mergeable`?

Comment: This is a FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type - TL;DR; use a typeclass, actually you are just reinventing `Semigroup`

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the comments, what you're looking for is not a subclass but a [typeclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class). It's not accurate to say that your values *are* instances of `Mergeable`, because that implies some sort of "global" mergeable functionality that just isn't realistic. Instead, it makes sense to say that `Mergeable` is a capability that can be applied to types. That is, "The type `Int` is a `Mergeable`", not "Every `Int` is itself mergeable".

I'll use the Scala 2 syntax here, since you haven't mentioned a Scala version. Note that [some of the syntax has changed in Scala 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-given-using-clauses.html).

We use a trait to describe our typeclass. Crucially, this trait is *not* going to be implemented by the concrete types like `Int` or `String`. It's going to be implemented by special singleton objects we make up.

```
trait Mergeable[A] {
  def merge(lhs: A, rhs: A): A
}
```

Now we provide instances for known types using the 'implicit'. keyword. We would use `given` in Scala 3.

```
implicit object IntIsMergeable extends Mergeable[Int] {
  def merge(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) = lhs + rhs
}

implicit object StringIsMergeable extends Mergeable[String] {
  def merge(lhs: String, rhs: String) = lhs + rhs
}

// Note: 'class' here since it's parameterized so it's not
// just one object.
implicit class ListIsMergeable[A] extends Mergeable[List[A]] {
  def merge(lhs: List[A], rhs: List[A]) = lhs ++ rhs
}
```

Now, if we want to write a function that takes mergeable objects and does something, we use implicit arguments. Let's say we wanted to write a function of three arguments that merges those three.

```
def merge3[A](x: A, y: A, z: A)(implicit mergeable: Mergeable[A]): A =
    mergeable.merge(mergeable.merge(x, y), z)
```

`merge3` is a function of four arguments: `x`, `y`, `z`, and `mergeable`. When we call `merge3`, we may (at our option) omit the fourth argument and Scala will just kind of automagically find one with the right type. So if we pass three integers, it knows it needs a `Mergeable[Int]`, and there's only one implicit instance of that around: the `IntIsMergeable` we wrote earlier. There's a lot of science going into how to resolve instances efficiently and intuitively, but that's the basic idea.

There are also a lot of conventions in place for writing good typeclasses people will understand, such as providing an `apply` that invokes an implicit instance and providing extension methods. The [Shapeless book](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html) goes into detail on some of these conventions if it's something you're interested in.

Finally, as hinted at in the comments, your `Mergeable` already has a name: it's called `Semigroup`. It's a well-understood mathematical object and is provided by both [Scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io/8/tc/Semigroup.html) and [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html).

Comment: Hmm after some study to familiarize myself with type classes and `Semigroup`, I'm not sure this actually answers my specific question. I need to parameterize `Mergeable` on more than just "is it an int", because as I explain in the question text I want some integers to only be summed, while others should only be multiplied. I think I might be able to figure out how to do this with `SemigroupK` though, if I define them something like `Multiplyable[Int]` and `Summable[Int]`...